# Is there a way to start exactly where one left off from a huge set of audio files?

Tags: audio, media-player, playlists, audiobook

So maybe a certain media player has this capability? I'm setting this up for a friend, and although I myself am a Linux user, he mostly uses Windows, so it would be preferred if this could work for Windows.

I think it could be done using playlists. The idea is that I can make a playlist with some playlist-capable media player, then have it somehow start off exactly where it was when it stopped playing last with a bookmark. I know some mp3 players can easily do this, but on the computer, it's a different story, and I'm not sure how it can be accomplished.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you just mean start at the same/next track or EXACTLY where it left off?  Most media players will remember where in a playlist you were...

Comment: I mean *exactly* where it left off. The same track, and the same moment within the track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JetAudio keeps file history similarly to the undo button.

I don't know about bookmarks, but when it re-opens, the track starts at the same timestamp it was at when the app last closed.